# Calculating the Gamma Posterior distribution Scikit Stats

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, posterior, gamma-distribution, ab-test

Say I have lots of data that I am using to model the weekly rate of some event, with 0 being the minimum frequency and 7 being the maximum frequency. I am looking to perform bayesian analysis on this data. I would like to use the gamma distribution as a conjugate prior. I can create this prior using the gamma.fit(data) method where data is a large array of frequency values(0-7 values). I am trying to basically update the prior with new information to find the posterior. Ive seen the equation for updating the gamma distribution, however, the equations are a little unclear when working with real data.

Here is some code to illustrate my point (values are > 7 obviously as this example was taken from an example problem.

```
# see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOSFibkuUis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma
pr = [8,10]
li = [12,11,15,2,9,12,13,10]

x1 = np.linspace(0,50,1000)

def calculateGammaParams(data):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    shape = (mean/std)**2
    scale = (std**2)/mean
    print("sh/sc:", shape, scale)
    return (shape, 0, scale)
  
s1,l1,sc1 = calculateGammaParams(pr) 

y1 = gamma.pdf(x1,s1,l1,sc1)


s2,l2,sc2 = calculateGammaParams(li) 

y2 = gamma.pdf(x1,s2,l2,sc2)


plt.plot(x1, y1, label=" prior")
plt.plot(x1, y2, label=" lik")
plt.legend();
```

From here, how would I go about calculating the posterior?

Comment: Please do not post video link and ask question on that. Express the specific problem. Also note that "pure coding" questions are out of scope here.

Comment: it is not pure coding. I am asking how to calculate the posterior. They video does not explain how to do this in my opinion. The two arrays at the top of the code show the prior data and the likelihood data. I would like to compute the posterior from the data.